# Simbiology trigger change in reaction rate (model delay)

Tags: matlab

I want to model a delay in Simbiology. More specifically, for the first 30 min nothing should happen (rate = 0) and then the rate should be switched to a differential expression.

I tried setting up a trigger with the following condition: time<1800s then product=0. Alternatively: time<1800 then Imax(the rate constant)=0.

Both approaches don't work and I can't find any help in the documentation. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seemingly it only works the other way round.

set the initial value of a parameter to 0 and then:

time>1800
then parameter=new_value

Furthermore, if you want to conditionally compare a quantity different from time one needs to multiply with another parameter equal to one that has the respective unit.

Example:
let the unit of `X` be 'Molarity', then then the event has to look like this:

```
X>10000*unit_parameter
```

`unit_parameter` is a globally defined parameter of value 1 with the unit 'Molarity'